# Redimensionar elementos de acordo com o tamanho do form

Tags: c#, winforms, redimensionamento

Tenho uma `GroupBox` dentro de um `Form` que tem o seguinte padrão:

```
Padrão de tela

- Form: 1290;700
- GroupBox Principal: 1260;600
```

Esse `Form` é aberto através de MDI. Utilizo uma função para centralizar esse form de acordo com o tamanho do monitor!

Porém, encontrei o seguinte problema quando tento abrir o sistema em um monitor que não é *wide* e a resolução é 1024X768 a minha `GroupBox` fica cortada. Como eu poderia fazer para o `Form` ter dimensionamento automático junto com todos os `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `Grids` que estão dentro dele?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use a propriedade Anchor do controle

Todos os controles WinForms têm uma propriedade chamada `Anchor`, esta propriedade serve justamente para definir o comportamento componente quando o seu `Parent` (ou `Parent` dele, e assim sucessivamente) for redimensionado.

Basicamente, você deve definir qual(ais) **lado(s)** do componente que irão seguir o componente `Parent`.

---

Aqui vai um exemplo (usei `Panel` ao invés de `GroupBox` para melhor visualização, mas a ideia é a mesma).

Eu defini a propriedade `Anchor` como `Top | Bottom | Left | Right`. O quer dizer que não importa o lado do meu form que for alterado, o painel sempre terá a mesma distância entre as bordas.

No lado esquerdo é o form com 200x200 e no lado direito é o mesmo form com 500x500.

[image: Forms com tamanhos diferentes e panel redimensionado]