# Mover botões em um formulário no Visual Studio por meio de um controle fixo

Tags: winforms

Eu quero adicionar botões ao meu formulário e ser capaz de movê-lo quando a aplicação estiver em execução, como fazer isso?

Eu gostaria também de aplicar um botão controle que defina se eles estão em estado fixado ou em modo flutuante.

O que eu preciso são de botoes que possam ter suas localizações alteradas de acordo com a conduta que for feita pelo usuário.

Comment: C# ou VB.NET? Você poderia [edit] e adicionar a tag da linguagem?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Redimensionar elementos de acordo com o tamanho do form](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116364/redimensionar-elementos-de-acordo-com-o-tamanho-do-form)

Comment: Como seria este mover? Quer arrastar os botões para posiciona-los dentro da tela? Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: você quer mover os controles (botões) com o mouse, tipo pra reorganizar em tempo de execução ?

Comment: Exatamente, quero mover os botoes dentro de um panel.